# CSS + FireFox: hiding scrollbar on iframe with scrolling=yes

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar, hide

I have an iframe with scrolling=yes. Is it possible to fully hide scrollbar using CSS for the Mozilla FireFox browser?

For instance, on the Internet Explorer I'm using this: Overflow-x: hidden; Overflow-y: hidden; - and it hides scrollbars, but FireFox ignores this CSS.

Here is screenshot from IE:

[alt text http://moismski.com/ie.png](http://moismski.com/ie.png)

Here is screenshot from FireFox:

[alt text http://moismski.com/firefox.png](http://moismski.com/firefox.png)

I forgot to mention that I put CSS, to say exactly like this `<style>body { overflow:hidden; }</style>` inside the iframe. I can't put class to iframe itself like `<iframe class="...">`

Iframe is put inside the `<DIV>...</DIV>`. I use it like a modal window.

Comment: Have you tried just `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: Yes, anyway it displays scrollbars!

Comment: Just use CSS: .frame {overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%}
I tried now. If you see scroll may be it is not of frame but some parent element?

Comment: Use next selector if you can modify div: 
#divId iframe{overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried setting explicit values for width/height on either the iframe or parent container? Also, does your iFrame contain anything?

EDIT:
Try:

```
div {overflow:hidden;}
div iframe {border:0;overflow:hidden;}
```

in your actual page that contains the div.

Comment: Yeah, I have width="100%" height="100%" on iframe setting! I have a registration form in the iframe.

Comment: Ahh. Ok, border adds to the dimensions so your iframe is actually getting bigger than the viewport. Try border:0; Unless you actually need to see the iframe?

Comment: I guess you can't edit your comments or im too scrubby to do so? The basic deal is, when you have anything that is 100% of it's container and anything adds additional border, padding or margin, it's going to generate a scrollbar. You might try posting your entire code along with all the css rules you are using. Otherwise, I can only guess. :)

Answer (score 2):

I've tried everything you said and looked at this two links either ( [How to remove scrollbars from Facebook iFrame application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194936/how-to-remove-scrollbars-from-facebook-iframe-application) - [facebook canvas height no scroll set in ie8 and firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990234/facebook-canvas-height-no-scroll-set-in-ie8-and-firefox)) that discuss the same problem, but it didn't work for me.

What worked for me was changing the canvas settings in the section advanced of app canvas configuration ( https://developers.facebook.com/apps ) to fixed canvas width (760px) and height (fixed at 800).

I hope this help you.