# Why is body tag using scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

My site is showing the horizontal scroll-bar unnecessarily.  There appears to be an extra 260px width of body on the right.  I'm using the 960gs grid system.

http://dev.keep-austin-level.gotpantheon.com/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your footer appears to be the culprit. I'm not entirely sure why, but adding `overflow:hidden;` to `#footer` solves your issue

Comment: There were two issues.  The ones fixed below and this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808808/facebook-like-button-causing-horizontal-scrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the problem is with your `div#footer-menu`.

You can play with the `ul.menu` within it to fit properly or do something like

```
#footer-menu{
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This solved the Facebook like problem.  Also included -ms-overflow-x:hidden in attempt to workaround ie8 (don't have so didn't test)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808808/facebook-like-button-causing-horizontal-scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

you could change the width of your facebook like button to something reasonable, or set the overflow to hidden.

Comment: After looking into this, it's a duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808808/facebook-like-button-causing-horizontal-scrollbar

Comment: I've had all kinds of problems with my facebook like buttons too. Just set the overflow to hidden or set the width of that button.

Comment: I think it does provide an answer considering the OP and I discussed the problem being the facebook button.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the definition of `#footer-menu ul.menu` and `#footer-menu ul.menu li`. In both cases you are using `left: 50%` which moves the block. If you want to align it to the right remove both of that `left: 50%` and add `float: right` to the `#footer-menu ul.menu`.

If you want to center them you can do this like this:

```
#footer-menu ul.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer-menu ul.menu li {
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 6px 6px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This was the root cause of 1/2 the problem.  I fixed it with this:

    #footer-menu {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #footer-menu ul.menu {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }