# facebook canvas height no scroll set in ie8 and firefox

Tags: facebook, iframe, size, height, fbjs

hey, i want to set a long page app without fb will limit the height of my app and append scroll
i did iframes& canvas and autoresize in settings and apply that code and its limits me in ie its shows scroll and in firefox its cuts the content:

the code is here:
http://pastebin.com/bmweWuTS

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am actually having the same issue, it started yesterday, but i have not changed the code. Facebook having some issues maybe?

I was using setAutoResize, but started getting the scrollbars, change to setSize (to something somewhat bigger then the content) and looks fine in firefox, but chrome still scrolls... odd but im thinking facebook problem.

Edit: Facebook forum thread on it: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=315870#p315870

Answer (score 2):

I've tried everything you said and looked at this two links either ( [CSS + FireFox: hiding scrollbar on iframe with scrolling=yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878188/css-firefox-hiding-scrollbar-on-iframe-with-scrolling-yes) - [CSS + FireFox: hiding scrollbar on iframe with scrolling=yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878188/css-firefox-hiding-scrollbar-on-iframe-with-scrolling-yes)) that discuss the same problem, but it didn't work for me.

What worked for me was changing the canvas settings in the section advanced of app canvas configuration ( https://developers.facebook.com/apps ) to fixed canvas width (760px) and height (fixed at 800).

I hope this help you.