# How to scroll content within fixed wrapper using native browser scroll

Tags: html, css

Easiest (I hope) to just check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/UG7un/

There is a fixed wrapper that covers the whole page with a 20px margin.  How do I get content to scroll within that wrapper?

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="content">
    <p>How can I get this to scroll within this white content area only, using the native browser scroll?</p>
</div>
<div id="photo"></div>
</div>

html {
    background:url(http://i1210.photobucket.com/albums/cc406/Ingutuks/2012/P5211369.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size:cover;
    }

#wrap {
    background:#fff;
    margin:20px;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#content {
    width:45%;
    padding:2.5%;
   float:left;
}

#photo {
    width:50%;
    background:url(http://i1351.photobucket.com/albums/p790/KrazyKobraRawr/Jojothecat_zps448af247.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: A creative solution for avoiding a double scroll - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878188/css-firefox-hiding-scrollbar-on-iframe-with-scrolling-yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly then you can use  `overflow:auto;` in your `wrap` div.

```
#wrap {
    background:#fff;
    margin:20px;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

it will show the scroller in your `wrap` div.

Comment: This is pretty close, would prefer scrollbar to show up in it's normal spot and not on the `wrap` div but this could work since the div is practically full window size.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify height;

```
#content {
    overflow:auto;
    height:360px;
    width:45%;
    padding:2.5%;
   float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UG7un/1/

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/UG7un/3/

Commented out the:

```
position:fixed;
```

and a couple lines of the JS.